# Why binding to attached property doesn't work?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Why binding to attached property doesn't work in this case.

I want to be able to bind ContentTemplate property of ContentPresenter to attached property extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate. In xaml below I've set that property in style setter in order to make code shorter. I've tried to set it on ContextMenu object as well. Each time I'm getting an **error**:

```
BindingExpression path error: '(extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate)' property not found on 'object' ''ContextMenu' (Name='')'. BindingExpression:Path=(extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate); DataItem='ContextMenu' (Name=''); target element is 'ContentPresenter' (Name=''); target property is 'ContentTemplate' (type 'DataTemplate')
```

**xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}" >
    <Setter Property="extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate" Value="{StaticResource DataTemplate}"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornerDecorator>
                        <Border  Margin="8" Padding="0 8 0 8" Background="White" Effect="{DynamicResource MDShadow2}"/>
                    </AdornerDecorator>

                    <Border Margin="8" Padding="0 8 0 8">

                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                            <Grid  HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0 -8 0 0">
                                <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding  (extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                            </Grid>

                            <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Cycle" />
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When binding to an attached property, add `Path=`

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding Path=(extent:ContextMenuExtension.HeaderDataTemplate), RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
```